# Finding series representation of $\frac{1}{P(D)}$ through ordinary division

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, differential-operators

I am studying ODEs from ordinary differential equations by Tenenbaum and Pollard. The book in its fifth chapter explains inverse operators for finding the particular solution of a constant coefficient linear ODE. It states that the particular solution $y_p = \frac{1}{P(D)}Q(x)$. It further goes on to prove this statement by using the following example:
$$ (D - a)y = bx^k $$
Which is equal to
$$ y_p = \frac{1}{-a(1 - \frac{D}{a})}bx^{k} $$
It is further stated that $ \frac{1}{1 - \frac{D}{a}} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{k}(\frac{D}{a})^n$ and states that this result was obtained by ordinary division. This is the part that confuses me. I do understand how this result could've been obtained by the usual Taylor series method but I do not understand how to obtain it from ordinary division (which I understand is polynomial long division) as the denominator is of a higher degree than the numerator. The book further goes on to state a similar result for a $n^{th}$ order linear constant coefficient ODE, which again according to the book was obtained through ordinary division. I would like to know how to use ordinary division to obtain a series representation for $\frac{1}{P(D)}$. Thank you.

Comment: I think you're missing a sum -- surely that inverse isn't equal to $\left(\frac Da\right)^n$ for all values of $n$.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. It should have read $n = 0,1,2,\ldots ,k$

Comment: That was a misunderstanding. I wasn't worried about an upper bound for $n$; even just for two values of $n$ it doesn't make sense that the operator should equal $\left(\frac Da\right)^n$ for both of them. My point was that there should be a sum over $n$ there.

Comment: I am extremely sorry. Yes I forgot to put a summation sign over there. Can you please tell me how would I obtain this series by ordinary division? I have been searching everywhere but all I find is polynomial long division with the order of the numerator strictly greater than the order of the denominator. I am frustrated by now.

Answer (score 1):

We have to perform the long division for $\frac{1}{1-\frac{D}{a}}$.
See the image attached.

[Long division for $\frac{1}{1-\frac{D}{a}}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywRUm.jpg)

In the book we also have an example with the following solution:

$y_p  = \frac{1}{9\bigg(1-\frac{D}{3}+\frac{4}{9}D^2\bigg)}(5x^2) = \frac{5}{9}\bigg(1+\frac{D}{3} - \frac{D^2}{3}\bigg)x^2$.

In this case we also have to use long division. See the image attached.

[Long division for $\frac{1}{\bigg(1-\frac{D}{3}+\frac{4}{9}D^2\bigg)}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eBOx.jpg)

It is worth noting that, as mentioned in the book, we do not need to go beyond the $D^2$ term since $D^3(x^2) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The more useful perspectives, to my mind, are to note that this is the series expansion of $1/(1-x)$ at $x=0$ or to verify the expansion by applying $1-\frac Da$ to it and noting that the sum telescopes, the highest term vanishes and the lowest term is $1$.

However, if you really want to do this by "ordinary division" (I'm not sure how "ordinary" division can be when it involves differential operators), I'd do it like this (writing $x$ for $\frac Da$ to avoid unnecessary notational clutter):

What mutliple of $1-x$ do we need to get $1$? We need $1$, so the first term is $1$: $1/(1-x)=1+\ldots$. Now we have $1-x$, but we don't want the $x$, so what multiple of $1-x$ do we need to get rid of it? That would be $x$, so the next term is $x$: $1/(1-x)=1+x+\ldots$. Now we have $1-x^2$ but we don't want the $x^2$, so what multiple of $1-x$ do we need to get rid of it? That would be $x^2$, and so on...